# How can multiple input files be read and processed in awk?

Tags: html, parsing, awk

I have a lot of .html files saved and I have already written a bunch of awk codes for Windows which do me the further text processing I need and works perfectly with one file, but I couldn't find a solution for reading the all of the files one ofter another and put it to results.txt?

```
awk -f C:/PLT2/parse.txt input_files > C:/PLT2/results.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a question for your OS, not for awk. The UNIX answer would be:

awk -f C:/PLT2/parse.txt input_file1 input_file2 input_fie3.... > C:/PLT2/results.txt

but you're not using UNIX, so....